# Why can't I claim my Season Journey rewards?

Tags: diablo-iii, ps4

This morning I completed the final two challenges in my Chapter III Season Journey, but I'm unable to claim my Haedrig's Gift cache because the game says I need to complete the previous step.

When I look at Chapter II journey, it's complete, but not marked as completed, as it's missing a gold seal, which I assume means completed. I have claimed my set items from chapter 2 already, so I've no idea what's left to complete.

What am I missing?

Chapter I
[image: Chapter 1 Complete]

Chapter II
[image: Chapter 2]

Chapter III
[image: Chapter 3]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I tend to leave my PS4 in rest mode, I actually closed Diablo 3 this morning. When I restarted the game, my Season Journey updated itself and I was able to claim my rewards.

So it seems that you have to actually restart the game from fresh to force an update.

Comment: Had the exact same problem on the Switch.